# Replace selected string in TextView

Tags: swift, textview

In the textview user select text, then clicks the button. How I can replace the selected text with a new one, which would be instead of the selected text when user press the button?

I try to use next code to get selected text:

```
guard let range = textViewText.selectedTextRange else {return}
```

But how I can replace it with a new string by button click?

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you've already solved this by now, but since there hasn't been an accurate answer posted yet, here's what I found that works:

```
textView.replace(UITextRange, withText: String)
```

You'll just plug in the `range` variable you created along with whatever String you want to replace it with.

Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

To change the text in the range with the new one:

```
textView.textStorage.replaceCharacters(in: range, with: string)
```

You need also to save range (as selectedRange) in a property of the class in order to access it inside the IBAction.

Comment: I try to save range with textViewText.selectedTextRange else {return}, but I get cannot convert value of type 'UITextRange' to expected argument type 'NSRange' (aka '_NSRange')

Comment: Could you show the lines of code where you get the error ?